# window:scroll not work with ngx-bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using [ngx-bootrap](https://www.google.com.vn/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwjdu_ajvcPdAhVUrpYKHe44BRkYABAAGgJ0bA&ae=1&sig=AOD64_35jdfBo01wRR4fJ5_yCJKQ8IBCig&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjPtO-jvcPdAhXGerwKHQrkAI0Q0Qx6BAgAEAI&adurl=http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap%3Fgclid%3DCj0KCQjwof3cBRD9ARIsAP8x70P4VBLrGq8jpmOZtWy7SkMWKb0uEc9mlB09nVlR-q0zZxOAR22i_FUaArwKEALw_wcB) for my angular 5 app. Now i want listen event when scroling page and I use  @HostListener('window:scroll', []), but it does not work with an open modal.

So how should i do

```
export class ScrollDirective {
    @HostListener("window:scroll", []) onWindowScroll() {
       console.log(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in ngx-bootstrap modal

```
 ngOnInit() {
 Observable.fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'scroll').subscribe((e: any) => {
     console.log(e.target);
  });
}
```